# Printing Html documents

Tags: asp.net, object, printing, djvu

i have a task to print html documents i m using window.print() along with some CSS the problem i m facing is printing of object tag in which a .djvu file is loaded i m using self created djvu viewer for viewing djvu file. problem is that object is streched when printing but on screen it is showing good view

thanks in advance

Comment: hey dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 0):

Set media style sheet = print for the printing version

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

more :
[CSS Media types and printer friendly pages](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can only guarantee print output if you use a file format such as PDF, you can generate these using the [free library iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Also you can explore using a separate stylesheet for printing, with the media tag set to "print".